# Creating a fixed html layout

Tags: css, html, layout

How would I create an HTML layout that has a fixed toolbar at the top, a fixed toolbar at the bottom - and a single centered DIV (centered, vertically and horizontally).  Also, I'm trying to get the centered DIV to be responsive, when user resizes window.

I've included a mockup/screenshot:

[image]

Comment: should the single center div respond to browser resizing? i.e. become smaller if the user decreases the vertical size of their window

Comment: If you can show us some code that you have experimented with, that would be very helpful. Coming here asking users to write code for you, based on your requirements, is *not* the basis of how SO operates.

Comment: Sure, I can include some.  Basically, the problem is - I can find solutions for fixed header, fixed footer, and centered div - but I'm having trouble putting it all together in one HTML layout.  It's not much code but I'm more of a backend dev and front end stuff is harder.  I'll include a codepen or something.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's what i have so far.  Notice the issue with centered content div.  http://jsfiddle.net/zk7we1cn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this Help?

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
}

#topToolBar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#bottomToolBar{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#centerDivWrapper{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#centerDiv{
  padding: 55px 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#centerDivContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #000; 
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="topToolBar"></div>
<div id="centerDivWrapper">
  <div id="centerDiv">
    <div id="centerDivContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottomToolBar"></div>
```

Comment: the center div wrapper isn't centered vertically in this example. put a border around the div and you can see only the left/right borders, but not the top/bottom as shown in the image.

Comment: Right, trying to fix it.

Comment: Done! Using the centerDiv as a wrapper to another div fixed the problem.

Comment: Andre - that is excellent!  Thanks - works well.